# cupy.cuda.runtime.CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorInsufficientDriver

Tags: chainer

I try to reproduce some codes with chainer. However, there is something wrong with cuda setting.

I used the conda environment with python 3.5 and ubuntu16.04. I used chainer 5.4.0 and cupy 5.4.0.

When I used "`cupy.show_config()`", the result is:

```
CuPy Version          : 5.4.0
CUDA Root             : /usr/local/cuda-10.1
CUDA Build Version    : 10010
CUDA Driver Version   : 0
CUDA Runtime Version  : CUDARuntimeError('cudaErrorInsufficientDriver: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version',)
cuDNN Build Version   : 7500
cuDNN Version         : 7500
NCCL Build Version    : None
NCCL Runtime Version  : None
```

there is always a CUDARuntimeError.

I expect to solve the problem of CUDARuntimeError.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by reinstalling cuda and cudnn.